# WooCommerce: Check if items are already in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I found this great snippet from this [website](https://joebuckle.me/quickie/woocommerce-check-if-item-already-in-cart/)

The following is the function to check if a specific product exists in cart:

```
        function woo_in_cart($product_id) {
        global $woocommerce;         
        foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $key => $val ) {
            $_product = $val['data'];

            if($product_id == $_product->id ) {
                return true;
            }
        }         
        return false;
        }
```

And this to use anywhere needed:

```
      if(woo_in_cart(123)) {
     // Product is already in cart
     }
```

The problem is how to use it to check multiple products like this:

```
      if(woo_in_cart(123,124,125,126...)) {
     // Product is already in cart
     }
```

Thanks.

[source](https://joebuckle.me/quickie/woocommerce-check-if-item-already-in-cart/)

Comment: You'll have to call the function multiple times or rewrite it.

Comment: you can check all product   if(woo_in_cart(123)) {
     // Product is already in cart
     }

Comment: I need this to be this way to check multiple products: if(woo_in_cart(123,124,125,126...)) {
     // Product is already in cart
     }

Comment: @LoicTheAztec mate as soon as i am on the pc i will run your code. Thanks for the help much appreciated.

Comment: make sure to add 
 ```if (is_admin()) return false;```
before your global $woocommerce in order so that this function doesn't run on the backend.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> **`global $woocommerce`** and **`$woocommerce->cart`** is **outdated** and simply **replaced** by **`WC()->cart`**

Here is a custom function with an argument that accepts a unique integer product ID or an array of product IDs, and that will return the number of matched Ids that are in cart.

The code handle any product type, including variable product and product variations:

```
function matched_cart_items( $search_products ) {
    $count = 0; // Initializing

    if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        // Loop though cart items
        foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            // Handling also variable products and their products variations
            $cart_item_ids = array($cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id']);

            // Handle a simple product Id (int or string) or an array of product Ids 
            if( ( is_array($search_products) && array_intersect($search_products, cart_item_ids) ) 
            || ( !is_array($search_products) && in_array($search_products, $cart_item_ids)
                $count++; // incrementing items count
        }
    }
    return $count; // returning matched items count 
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).

Code is tested and works.

---

**USAGE:**

1) For a unique product ID (integer):

```
$product_id = 102;

// Usage as a condition in an if statement
if( 0 < matched_cart_items($product_id) ){
    echo '<p>There is "'. matched_cart_items($product_id) .'"matched items in cart</p><br>';
} else {
    echo '<p>NO matched items in cart</p><br>';
}
```

2) For an array of product IDs:

```
$product_ids = array(102,107,118);

// Usage as a condition in an if statement
if( 0 < matched_cart_items($product_ids) ){
    echo '<p>There is "'. matched_cart_items($product_ids) .'"matched items in cart</p><br>';
} else {
    echo '<p>NO matched items in cart</p><br>';
}
```

3) For an array of product IDs for 3 or more matched cart items for example:

```
$product_ids = array(102, 107, 118, 124, 137);

// Usage as a condition in an if statement (for 3 matched items or more)
if( 3 <= matched_cart_items($product_ids) ){
    echo '<p>There is "'. matched_cart_items($product_ids) .'"matched items in cart</p><br>';
} else {
    echo '<p>NO matched items in cart</p><br>';
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply its not working for me. $product_ids = array(7657,7995,8000,7999,7998,7997,7996); 
if(  0 < matched_cart_items($product_ids) ) {

Comment: @mysticalghoul Ok let me check and retest-it on my test server, this should be solved quickly (the idea for this script is there)… If you like we can chat on Skype (my ID is `marsloic`) as chat in here is too prehistorical…

Comment: 's' missing in variable name $product_id in usage #1, other than that, perfect!

Comment: @Gangesh I have changed that… Thanks.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$count' (T_VARIABLE)

Answer (score 9):

Maybe something simpler, first we get product ids in cart :

```
$product_ids = array_merge(
  wp_list_pluck(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents(), 'variation_id'),
  wp_list_pluck(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents(), 'product_id')
);
```

Now if you want to check one product just simply use [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function :

```
in_array(123, $product_ids);
```

and for more than one product:

```
array_intersect([123, 345, 567], $product_ids);
```

Comment: Nice short version!

Answer (score 3):

**Case 1 : Pass Array As an argument.**

```
 function woo_in_cart($arr_product_id) {
        global $woocommerce;         
        $cartarray=array();

        foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $key => $val ) {
            $_product = $val['data'];
            array_push($cartarray,$_product->id);
        }         
        $result = !empty(array_intersect($cartarray,$arr_product_id));
        return $result;

        }
```

How to call function

```
$is_incart=array(2,4,8,11);
print_r(woo_in_cart($is_incart));
```

**Case 2 : Use Code that you run.**

```
$is_in_product_cart=array(123,124,125,126,..);

foreach($is_in_product_cart as $is_in_cart ) 
    if(woo_in_cart($is_in_cart))
    {
        // Product is already in cart
    }
}
```

Comment: "Cant use function return value"

Comment: error is on this: $result = !empty(array_intersect($cartarray,$arr_product_id));

Comment: first check op of this : print_r(array_intersect($cartarray,$arr_product_id));

Comment: I cant check anything function crashes the website

Comment: Yes on a hosting server

Comment: Dont think so if its not working on a live website then there is no point of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131160/discussion-between-mysticalghoul-and-vasim-vanzara).

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in the woo_in_cart function.
Here the correct one:

```
 function woo_in_cart($arr_product_id) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cartarray=array();

    foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $key => $val ) {
       $_product = $val['product_id'];
       array_push($cartarray,$_product);
    }

    if (!empty($cartarray)) {
       $result = array_intersect($cartarray,$arr_product_id);
    }

    if (!empty($result)) {
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    };

}
```

Here an example of usage:

```
//Set IDs Array variable

$my_products_ids_array = array(22,23,465);
if (woo_in_cart($my_products_ids_array)) {
  echo 'ohh yeah there some of that products in!';
}else {
  echo 'no matching products :(';
}
```