# Same product id not added in a cart page woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

How to prevent same product id can't add in a cart while another product id add in cart list Woocommerce before hook .

Comment: Please show us what you have tried till now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce - Check if item's are already in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262426/woocommerce-check-if-items-are-already-in-cart)

Comment: This question is just not understandable… Please try to better explain it better and clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the code to solve same product id can't add twice in a cart while different product id added in cart may help you.....Not sure

add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'bbloomer_find_product_in_cart'); 

   function bbloomer_find_product_in_cart($product_id) {
        global $woocommerce;         
        foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $key => $val ) {
            $_product = $val['data'];

            if($product_id == $_product->id ) {
             $notice = 'Product ID ' . $product_id . 'Allready is in the Cart choose another product!';
            wc_print_notice( $notice, 'notice' );
                return false;
            } 
        }         
        return true;
        }
```